# No battery indicator when logged in as second (non-sudo) user

Tags: unity, indicator, sudo, power-management, battery

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity.

I have a setup with two users, one with sudo privileges for admin use, and one without for daily use.

When logged in as the non-privileged user, there's no battery indicator.

When logged in as the sudo user, the battery indicator is present.

Checking in dconf (with dconf-editor), the battery indicator seems to be enabled. And the superuser doesn't seem to be member of any groups which govern power management. So what do I need to enable the battery indicator for ALL users?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution to this. It took some time, so I'll just write it up here in case someone has the same problem.

Apparently, the problem was this user's Gnome settings. In `dconf-editor`, it was easy to verify that in `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power` the key `active`was set to `false`.

I figured it out after seeing that when running `gnome-control-center` from the command line, I got this error message in the output:

```
Error getting devices:GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power' on object at path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power
```

After running

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true
```

and logging out & in again, everything worked fine.

I have no idea how the key came to be turned off in the first place.